# Zod validator / validate image

Tags: javascript, typeorm, zod

I have a problem, I need to validate an image with `zod`. I am searching for 3 hours. I can't find out on validating the image? Can anyone help me out to fix this? `zod` must have image validate yes?

```js
const payloadSchema = z.object({
    image: z.record(z.string()),
})
```

Find something like this, but how can I add the image that is 3 mb max and it's type must be "`jpg`" "`png`" or "`gif`"

Answer (score 22):

Try this it, it seems simple and it works for me:

```
const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5000000;
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/webp"];

const someSchema = z.object({
  image: z
    .any()
    .refine((file) => file?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, `Max image size is 5MB.`)
    .refine(
      (file) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(file?.type),
      "Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported."
    )
})
```

And then the error should be displayed with:

```
formState.errors?.image?.message
```

One thing to note though is what kind of object are you getting from your input. Check if its a File object or a File[] array. I am using it with react-dropzone so I configured it to save a single File object. If it were an array you would have to change the schema to this:

```
const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5000000;
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/webp"];

const someSchema = z.object({
  image: z
    .any()
    .refine((files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, `Max image size is 5MB.`)
    .refine(
      (files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type),
      "Only .jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp formats are supported."
    )
})
```

Comment: const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 500000; i think the size would be 5000000. you can edit that out.
thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: For anyone else still encountering this problem, there is an ongoing thread with newer solutions than the ones posted here

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/387#issuecomment-1774603011

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem as you did and discovered a simpler way to solve it.

I'm also using Dropzone, but the concept is the same if you're using the File type, as long as it's not a vector file. Just don't use the "transform" and understand that the refinement will be for a single file.

```js
    avatar: z
    .custom<FileList>()
    .transform((file) => file.length > 0 && file.item(0))
    .refine((file) => !file || (!!file && file.size <= 10 * 1024 * 1024), {
      message: "The profile picture must be a maximum of 10MB.",
    })
    .refine((file) => !file || (!!file && file.type?.startsWith("image")), {
      message: "Only images are allowed to be sent.",
    }),
```

Answer (score 4):

I would go about this by adding a refinement to a zod schema for `File`. The [`superRefine`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#superrefine) helper can be used to attach new issues to an existing schema as follow up validations.

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const MB_BYTES = 1000000; // Number of bytes in a megabyte.

// This is the list of mime types you will accept with the schema
const ACCEPTED_MIME_TYPES = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];

// This is a file validation with a few extra checks in the `superRefine`.
// The `refine` method could also be used, but `superRefine` offers better
// control over when the errors are added and can include specific information
// about the value being parsed.
const imageSchema = z.instanceof(File).superRefine((f, ctx) => {
  // First, add an issue if the mime type is wrong.
  if (!ACCEPTED_MIME_TYPES.includes(f.type)) {
    ctx.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
      message: `File must be one of [${ACCEPTED_MIME_TYPES.join(
        ", "
      )}] but was ${f.type}`
    });
  }
  // Next add an issue if the file size is too large.
  if (f.size > 3 * MB_BYTES) {
    ctx.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.too_big,
      type: "array",
      message: `The file must not be larger than ${3 * MB_BYTES} bytes: ${
        f.size
      }`,
      maximum: 3 * MB_BYTES,
      inclusive: true
    });
  }
});
```

This should validate with the parameters you defined, but assumes you have a handle on the `File` that you are validating. If you are getting files from an `<input type="file" />` element, you could potentially sidestep needing to validate the MIME type by adding an [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#accept) attribute to your input.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to create an image upload with multiple files allowed and have to limit the file type to `png, jpg, jpeg and webp`

I faced the same issue, so after going through all the answers available here and also looking at the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/387#issuecomment-1774603011) for the Image Validation. { In the issue, they had mentioned to use `z.instanceof(File)` for `node -v >=20.0.0`, but it didn't work for me even though I'm using `v20.10.0`, so don't know about that }. This is my solution for the problem it works fine for all the cases I could think of.

```
const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5000000
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = [
 'image/jpeg',
 'image/jpg',
 'image/png',
 'image/webp',
]

image: z
  .any()
  // To not allow empty files
  .refine((files) => files?.length >= 1, { message: 'Image is required.' })
  // To not allow files other than images
  .refine((files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type), {
    message: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp files are accepted.',
   })
  // To not allow files larger than 5MB
  .refine((files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE, {
    message: `Max file size is 5MB.`,
   }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It works for me. also pls check if you have a file array or a file object and make changes accordingly. i have also added file required validation also if needed

```
const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 3000000;
function checkFileType(file: File) { // file type checking
    if (file?.name) {
        const fileType = file.name.split(".").pop();
        if (["gif", "png", "jpg"].includes(fileType)) return true; 
    }
    return false;
}

export const fileSchema = z.object({
  z.any()
   .refine((file: File) => file?.length !== 0, "File is required") // If you also wanna validate if the file exists
   .refine((file) => file.size < MAX_FILE_SIZE, "Max size is 3MB.") // file size validation
   .refine((file) => checkFileType(file), "Only .jpg, .gif, .png formats are supported."),` 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem in `Zod` image validation and I tried many ways to solve it. finally I got my solution as bellow code:

const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 500000;
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = [
"image/jpeg",
"image/jpg",
"image/png",
"image/webp",
];

```
image: z
    .any()
    .refine((files) => files?.length == 1, "Image is required.")
    .refine(
      (files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE,
      `Max file size is 5MB.`
    )
    .refine(
      (files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type),
      ".jpg, .jpeg, .png and .webp files are accepted."
    ),
```